# Arquillian with Open Liberty

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss-arquillian, open-liberty

Im trying to add some simple integration tests for my application. Im following the guide here: https://openliberty.io/guides/arquillian-managed.html

However, when I try to run the tests I get an error saying

```
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.831 sec <<< FAILURE!
app.controllers.ServiceTest  Time elapsed: 0.83 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.jboss.arquillian.container.spi.ConfigurationException: wlpHome is required for initialization
        at io.openliberty.arquillian.managed.WLPManagedContainerConfiguration.validate(WLPManagedContainerConfiguration.java:59)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.ContainerImpl.createDeployableConfiguration(ContainerImpl.java:110)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.ContainerImpl.setup(ContainerImpl.java:165)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$7.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:127)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$7.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:124)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.forContainer(ContainerLifecycleController.java:208)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.setupContainer(ContainerLifecycleController.java:124)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:103)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:90)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.createContainerContext(ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.java:54)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:133)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:105)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:62)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$1.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:58)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$1.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:52)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.forEachContainer(ContainerLifecycleController.java:172)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.setupContainers(ContainerLifecycleController.java:52)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:103)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:90)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:133)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:105)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:62)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.execute(ContainerEventController.java:82)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:103)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:90)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:69)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:133)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:105)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.beforeSuite(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:71)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.AdaptorManager.initializeAdaptor(AdaptorManager.java:23)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.AdaptorManagerWithNotifier.initializeAdaptor(AdaptorManagerWithNotifier.java:19)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:109)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
```

And this is my **pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>net.wasdev.wlp.maven.parent</groupId>
        <artifactId>liberty-maven-app-parent</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.lunch.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>lunch-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>


    <properties>
        <java.min.version>11</java.min.version>
        <maven.min.version>3.0.5</maven.min.version>
        <liberty-maven-plugin.version>3.0.M1</liberty-maven-plugin.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.0.Final</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bitbucket.b_c</groupId>
            <artifactId>jose4j</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13-beta-3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.0-M1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.0-M1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.openliberty.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-liberty-managed-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.6</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap</groupId>
            <artifactId>shrinkwrap-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <packagingExcludes>pom.xml</packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>failsafe-integration-test</id>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.java</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>failsafe-verify</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <summaryFile>
                        ${project.build.directory}/test-reports/it/failsafe-summary.xml
                    </summaryFile>
                    <reportsDirectory>
                        ${project.build.directory}/test-reports/it
                    </reportsDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.wasdev.wlp.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>liberty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <!-- Specify configuration, executions for liberty-maven-plugin -->
                <configuration>
                    <serverName>ArquillianManagedServer</serverName>
                    <assemblyArtifact>
                        <groupId>io.openliberty</groupId>
                        <artifactId>openliberty-runtime</artifactId>
                        <version>[18.0.0.4,)</version>
                        <type>zip</type>
                    </assemblyArtifact>
                    <configFile>src/main/wlp/config/server.xml</configFile>
                    <packageFile>${project.build.directory}/lunchapp.zip</packageFile>
                    <include>usr</include>
                    <bootstrapProperties>
                        <default.http.port>9080</default.http.port>
                    </bootstrapProperties>
                    <skipTestServer>true</skipTestServer>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install-apps</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <looseApplication>true</looseApplication>
                            <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
                            <installAppPackages>project</installAppPackages>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>package-app</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/wlp-package</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>configure-arquillian-xml</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>configure-arquillian</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Could you post the whole build output from the command you are running (usually `mvn install`) and the contents of the file located in `target/test-classes/arquillian.xml`?

Comment: Im running mvn clean test and I do not have an arquillian.xml file. The tests run if i uncomment my test file and run mvn clean install, after that I can run mvn test and everything works fine. But when I try to compile with the test files I get the error.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to run `mvn integration-test` instead of `mvn test` since the failsafe plugin is bound to the `integration-test` phase. Furthermore, you can see in the pom.xml that there is a [configure-arquillian](https://github.com/OpenLiberty/ci.maven/blob/master/docs/configure-arquillian.md#configure-arquillian) goal from the `liberty-maven-plugin` that is bound to the `pre-integration-test` phase. This goal is responsible for generating the `arquillian.xml` file in `target/test-classes/arquillian.xml`. Without that generated file, you will not have the proper Arquillian configuration and that is why you are seeing the `org.jboss.arquillian.container.spi.ConfigurationException: wlpHome is required for initialization` error message.

The `test` phase in Maven is intended for unit tests and is run earlier in the [build lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) than `integration-test` and `pre-integration-test`. Everything works after running the `install` phase since doing so will run these two phases as well.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. The command 'mvn install' does not work, if I try to run that command I will get the same error saying "wlpHome is missing". But if i remove the test file completly, then run 'mvn clean install' and then add back the test file and run 'mvn test' everything works.

Comment: Have you made changes to the sample project in terms of changing the binding of the tests to run in the `test` phase instead of the `integration-test` phase? The sample project does not run any tests when running `mvn test` since there are no unit tests to run.